# Laragear / WebAuthn ERROR POST /webauthn/register 422 at webauthn.js:159

Tags: javascript, laravel, webauthn

#### HELP

Please i am trying to use Laragear/WebAuthn in my app i have to upgrade to laravel 9 in other to use this package

after setting it up I got an Issue registering Device...
I get 422 Error Code

Here is the response from console

```
POST https://example.com/webauthn/register 422
#fetch @ webauthn.js:159
register @ webauthn.js:317
await in register (async)
(anonymous) @ settings:1690
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Response {type: 'basic', url: 'https://example.com/webauthn/register', redirected: false, status: 422, ok: false, …}
```

Here are my codes for registration

```
const webAuthn = new WebAuthn({
    registerOptions: '/webauthn/register/options',
    register: '/webauthn/register',
});

webAuthn.register()
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    //My Codes
})
.catch(response => {
    console.log(response);
   //My Codes
})
```

Please How will I solve this or what could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the webauthn routes to your routes file?

```
// web.php
use Laragear\WebAuthn\WebAuthn;

// WebAuthn Routes
WebAuthn::routes();
```